# What was the purpose of the octagonal room in Heaven Sent?

Tags: doctor-who

There was an octagonal room, with an octagon in the centre of the floor. In the centre there was some sand and dust, with arrows pointing towards the central point.

[image]

**What was the importance of that room?**

Comment: Thanks for posting this, i loved the episode but I didn't get this at all until now :)

Comment: also thanks for editing too. question is much more clear now.

Comment: Okay. That explains the arrows. Try this one. Who left the clothing for the Doctor in the fireplace room? Does it come with the room or did the original copy choose to walk around naked? ... Maybe this is just a casual loop, you might think, but remember... There was no time travel in this episode. Just clever use of a teleporter. (Fancy 3D printer.) Perhaps the original copy pieced everything together over a longer amount of time and arranged the bread crumbs to speed up the process... On heck of bird.

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but isn't one. To ask a new question, click the 'Ask Question' button in the top right.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**The gap in the floor is a missing stone. It’s the tile that the Doctor digs up in the courtyard.**

After he leaves the room with the octagonal gap, he goes into the courtyard and starts digging. When he first strikes the stone, we see his mind flash to the room with the arrows – it’s implying that this would fit into the gap. (We don’t see the full stone, but the Doctor can presumably feel the edges of it under the dirt, and feels the octagonal edges.)

This is the flashback image, which shows the space where the tile would fit:

[image]

It makes it clear that the message on this stone is important, and that this is part of the breadcrumb trail.

Why bury it at all? Two reasons:

- It forces the Doctor to dig a grave-like hole, the idea of which I’m sure amused the designer of the castle.
- The message isn’t too obvious, to try to throw him off the scent of the trap in Room 12.

Comment: I thought it was buried to ensure The Doctor stayed in the room long enough whilst digging it up for The Veil to reach him. He remarked that it took 81 minutes for it to travel from one side of the castle to the other, and it would take at least that long for him to dig up the grave. There was only one way in or out of the garden, and The Veil was waiting outside the door until he had finished digging, so when he had uncovered the next breadcrumb he would be forced to confess in order to escape.

Comment: I assumed that he buried it under the yard, so that when all the castle "resets", his writing on the stone wouldnt - since technically it is *under* the castle. Though thinking about it, that doesnt explain why the stone is still missing from the room, nor the chalkmarks on the floor there....